# How is と used here?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

The following is an excerpt from an e-mail conversation between me and my language partner.

For some pre- and posttext:
ほかに例を挙げると、

ジョンは去年まで３年間日本で働いている。

「去年まで３年間」がはっきりと過去を表しているので、これはジョンの過去の経験で、今は働いていないことが分かります。

ジョンはこの３年間日本で働いている。

The sentence in question:
「去年まで３年間」がはっきり**と**過去を表しているので、これはジョンの過去の経験で、今は働いていないことが分かります。

My attempt at translation:
"Because 'By last year three years' clearly reveals the past, I know that it is an experience from john's past and that he doesn't work anymore."

I understood the sentence as translated above, but I have no idea what this と in bold is supposed to do or mean ^^ 
according to jisho, it can be an adverb, and thats the way I translated it. It can also be a suru verb, but I didn't know how to translate it on that premise.