# A bit confused with と in ひょっこりと

Tags: adverbs

> 彼女は今になって到着し、廊下から**ひょっこりと**顔を出す。

This と looks like it comes from the word behind, so ひょっこり but when looking at a dictionary I found that ひょっこり is not an adjective which can take と. Why is と placed after this adverb, then?

For instance, it is specified that ゆっくり is an adverb which can take the と particle, however, there is no mention of that regarding ひょっこり.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%e3%81%a8

Comment: Hmm.. it does not entirely answer my question. I'm wondering why there are so-called "と" adjectives if some words can take と with being such an adjective.

Comment: I don't know the reason why your dictionary has no mention about it, but "ひょっこり" is adverb which can precede "と" and we sometimes use it without "と" like: "廊下からひょっこり顔を出す。" Some adverbs can take "と".

Comment: Oh, really? I looked on Jisho.org and there was no mention of と in there.

Comment: I would recommend checking a Japanese dictionary before basing anything on Jisho. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%82%8A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ひょっこり definitely belongs to the "adverb taking the 'to' particle" category, which is described in the following questions:

- [What role does と play in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36764/5010)
- [What is the purpose of adding と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24943/5010)
- [What does adding と after an adverb do?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42163/5010)
- [How is と used here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55234/5010)

I don't know why jisho doesn't mention it can (optionally) take と. It may be simply because this word is relatively uncommon.